# How to draw the function $y'(x) = y(x)(y(x)-1)^{1/3}$ qualitatively?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, recreational-mathematics, cauchy-problem

Let $k \in R$, consider the following Cauchy problem

$$y'(x) = y(x)(y(x)-1)^{1/3} $$
$$y(0) = k $$

To draw the graph of solutions, defining the domain, studying the monotonicity, the convexity, and limits at the extrema of the domain for

$1)k<0$ 
$2)k\in(0,1)$
$3)k>1$
$4)k=1$

I don't understand how to proceed after knowing the fact that $y =0 $ and $y = 1$ are the only constant solutions and these cannot be crossed given the uniqueness. However, I have the solution yet I am facing the problem of understanding key concepts. I have attached the link below to get a look. I have tried solving this using the slope-field method but it came out very wrong. I request anyone who can discuss or provide a slightest hint to solve this.

https://mate.unipv.it/rocca/Solutions-Adv.Math.Meth.January25-2022.pdf

Comment: If you can code in Matlab, use ode45 and refer to https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/301863-how-to-solve-a-system-of-first-order-differential-equation-in-matlab

Comment: The third root is the cube root? That is, negative arguments give negative results? Note that at $y=1$ the function is not locally Lipschitz, and indeed solutions crossing that line can be constructed.